# Whatsapp ChatStorage.sqlite file corrupted

Tags: ios, sqlite, whatsapp

I have figured that some parts of my sqlite file are corrupted. I don't have any other backup than this with error. Please help as I have almost my lifetime chats included in this file.

Below is the result from the pragma integrity check:

```
sqlite> .open ChatStorage.sqlite
sqlite> analyze;
Error: database disk image is malformed
sqlite> pragma foreign_key_check;
sqlite> PRAGMA integrity_check;
*** in database main ***
On page 39293 at right child: Failed to read ptrmap key=41324
Page 41324: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
On page 39301 at right child: Failed to read ptrmap key=41326
Page 41326: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
Page 41325 is never used
row 88466 missing from index ZWAMESSAGE_ZSTANZAID_INDEX
row 88467 missing from index ZWAMESSAGE_ZSTANZAID_INDEX
row 88851 missing from index ZWAMESSAGE_ZSTANZAID_INDEX
row 90450 missing from index ZWAMESSAGE_ZSTANZAID_INDEX
row 99205 missing from index ZWAMESSAGE_ZSTANZAID_INDEX
row 175874 missing from index ZWAMESSAGE_ZSTANZAID_INDEX
row 179438 missing from index ZWAMESSAGE_ZSTANZAID_INDEX
row 180340 missing from index ZWAMESSAGE_ZSTANZAID_INDEX
sqlite> .exit
```

There are more rows missing from index.

Please let me know a way to fix this.
Also, are there some tools available that can automatically resolve this?
I am not a programmer by profession but I do understand coding and can try resolving this if there are a handful of commands to get this through.

Comment: This really isn't a programming question. You should post this in a more appropriate place. Perhaps https://superuser.com